# ApplicationContext.Current is coming null

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco6

I found same question in stack over flow as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51317572/umbraco-applicationcontext-current-is-null) and tried same think but still I am receiving ApplicationContext.Current as null.

I am making the web service where I need to pull out a couple of pieces of data from an Umbraco database. I don't need any of the Umbraco views or any of that stuff. I'm new to the Umbraco Core libraries.

What I did was get a below reference to my new web service project

```
umbraco.dll
Umbraco.Core.dll
umbraco.DataLayer.dll
umbraco.editorControls.dll
umbraco.MacroEngines.dll
umbraco.providers.dll
Umbraco.Web.UI.dll
umbraco.XmlSerializers.dll
UmbracoExamine.dll
```

And the below class code where I am receiving ApplicationContext.Current as null

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Umbraco.Web.Mvc;
using umbraco.MacroEngines;
using Umbraco.Web;
using Umbraco.Web.WebApi;
using umbraco.NodeFactory;
using Umbraco.Core;
using Umbraco.Core.Models;
using Umbraco.Core.Services;
using umbraco.cms.businesslogic.media;
using umbraco.BusinessLogic;
using System.Configuration;
using log4net;
using System.Reflection;
using Umbraco.Core.Logging;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Stripe;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.Security;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public class RegisterUserController : UmbracoApiController
{
    public static string UmbracoConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["umbracoDbDSN"].ConnectionString;

    public static IMemberService memberService = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MemberService;// Here I am getting ApplicationContext.Current as null

}
```

But I am calling this class I am getting ApplicationContext.Current as null.
So because of that I have Many methods in this class which works on memberService and due to this null reference they are not working. Even other methods which are not using member service are not being called.

Comment: Did you read the answer in the linked post?

Comment: @mjwills yes they asked to add  Umbraco Api Controller  which I had done and also in class I have get the assembly reference as using Umbraco.Web;
using Umbraco.Web.WebApi;

Comment: Please check, if the connection string is working fine.

Comment: @Nivs yes it is working fine, The connection string is fetched properly

Answer (score 0):

For me, the code below seems to work.

```
public class TestApiController : UmbracoApiController
{
    private static string _umbracoConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["umbracoDbDSN"].ConnectionString;

    private static IMemberService _memberService = global::Umbraco.Core.ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MemberService;

    public int GetTest()
    {
        var memberCount = _memberService.Count();
        return memberCount;
    }
}
```

If the above code isn't working for you e.g. with AJAX, try the below code:

```
public class TestApiController : UmbracoApiController
{
    public int GetTest()
    {
        var ms = Services.MemberService;
        return ms.Count();
    }
}
```

Comment: global::Umbraco.Core.ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MemberService; is giving Umbraco.Core.ApplicationContext is null